# How to make simple Bar Chart based on AndroidPlot?

Tags: java, android, charts, render, androidplot

I already figure several changes on android plot examples given from its website. But i'm still unable to make the Bar Chart become similar to the picture below:

[image]

Does anyone has a clear Idea which part that I forgot?

Here is my code:

```
 private void prepareSuccessRate() {

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    formatter3 = new MyBarFormatter(Color.argb(200, 100, 100, 150),
            Color.LTGRAY);

    formatter2 = new MyBarFormatter(Color.argb(200, 50, 100, 100),
            Color.YELLOW);

    // add a dark, semi-transparent background to the selection label
    // widget:
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setARGB(100, 0, 0, 0);

    // reduce the number of range labels

    plot.setRangeLowerBoundary(0, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setGridPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);

    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);
    plot.setTicksPerDomainLabel(1);

    // setup check box listers:
    series1CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s1CheckBox);
    series2CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s2CheckBox);

    // obtaining file calculating variables
    TransfObject.prepareData();

    if (TransfObject.manyXP() != 0) {

        // display it on UI
        ToastObject.postFastMessage("ada "+TransfObject.TotalFailedXP());

        // success & failure data
        series1Numbers = getSingleValueNumber(TransfObject.TotalSuccessXP());
        series1aNumbers = getSingleValueNumber(TransfObject.TotalFailedXP());

        series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, sTitleSuccess);

        series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1aNumbers),
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, sTitleFailed);

        series2Numbers = getManyOrderedExp(1);

        // max y-value
        plot.setRangeTopMax(TransfObject.manyXP());
        plot.setRangeBottomMax(3);

        plot.setDomainValueFormat(new GraphXLabelFormat());

        updatePlot();

    }

    plot.setRangeLabel(sTitleNumberOfExp);
    plot.setTitle("Success Rate");
    plot.setDomainLabel(sDomainLabel);

}


 private void updatePlot() {

    // Remove all current series from each plot
    Iterator<XYSeries> iterator1 = plot.getSeriesSet().iterator();
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        XYSeries setElement = iterator1.next();
        plot.removeSeries(setElement);
    }

    if (repType == Stats.BY_SUCCESS_RATE) {
        // displaying success rate
        // color
        plot.addSeries(series1, formatter3);
        plot.addSeries(series2, formatter2);

    } else if (repType == Stats.BY_TRANSFER_SPEED) {
        // displaying transfer speed
        // color
        plot.addSeries(series1, formatter2);

    } else if (repType == Stats.BY_TRANSFER_TIME) {
        // displaying transfer time
        // color
        plot.addSeries(series1, formatter1);
    }

    MyBarRenderer renderer = ((MyBarRenderer) plot
            .getRenderer(MyBarRenderer.class));
    renderer.setBarRenderStyle((BarRenderer.BarRenderStyle) BarRenderer.BarRenderStyle.SIDE_BY_SIDE);
    renderer.setBarWidthStyle((BarRenderer.BarWidthStyle) BarRenderer.BarWidthStyle.FIXED_WIDTH);
    renderer.setBarWidth(50);

    plot.redraw();

}
```